# Best way to define custom settings for desktop-application?

Tags: java, settings, desktop

If you have a Java desktop application, what is the best way to store window-related settings like window position, window state (maximized, ...), ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Java Preferences API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/preferences.html)? It's the first thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

This was one of the problems the [Swing Application Framework](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingappfr/) was going to solve (see the section on session state). However, that project has stopped though there is a fork called [Better Swing Application Framework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bsaf/) that is still under development.